# add_message() argument must be an HttpRequest object, not 'str'

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a django website which translates a dna chain into a protein. Basically, you input a group of letters divisible by three and then it gets translated into a protein. This part of the code works perfectly. However, I am experiencing some troubles with the messages. If you want to see the documentation of django messages, here it is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/.

What I want to do is: when you input a group of letters which isn't divisible by three, it should raise a message with the level or error (message.error). Here's the code:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    def translate_amino(self, codon):
        return self.amino_mapper.get(codon, "")


   

    def build_protein(self, request, phrase):
        protein = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(phrase):
            codon = phrase[i: i + 3]
            amino = self.translate_amino(codon)
            if amino:
                protein.append(amino)
            else:
                print(f"The codon {codon} is not in self.mapper_1")
            i += 3
        if len(phrase) % 3:
            messages.error(request, 'DNA CHAIN INVALID')
        else:
            return protein
    


    

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'main/translator.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phrase = request.POST.get('text', 'translation')
        protein = request.POST.get('text','protein')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'translation': self.translate(phrase), 'protein': ", ".join(self.build_protein(protein, phrase))})
```

However, when I run the code, this error gets raised:

add_message() argument must be an HttpRequest object, not 'str'.

```
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'translation': self.translate(phrase), 'protein': ", ".join(self.build_protein(protein, phrase))}) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\marcv\OneDrive\Escriptori\Translate\Scripts\src\translator\views.py, line 176, in build_protein
            messages.error(request, 'DNA CHAIN INVALID')
```

I believe this comes from the if statement where i type the message.error.

However, I don't know how to solve it.

PS: If you need the calling methods, don't hesitate in telling me

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: I've just edited the post with the full traceback

Comment: that is not the traceback, but the view. The traceback lists all method calls that result in the error, together with the values for the parameters.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.

Comment: Now, here's the traceback. It says the error is in the messages.error line and in the calling method post

Comment: Ok, problem solved. Now there's another error but I do believe I know the solution. Anyways, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You make a function call with:

```
'protein': ', '.join(self.build_protein(protein, phrase))
```

this means that the second parameter of `def build_protein(self, request, phrase)` is not a request object, but the value for `protein`. You should pass the request, so:

```
'protein': ', '.join(self.build_protein(request, phrase))
```

in your `build_protein(…)` method, you better also return a value if the condition has not been met, since if the method returns `None`, `''.join(None)` will raise an error:

```
def build_protein(self, request, phrase):
    protein = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(phrase):
        codon = phrase[i: i + 3]
        amino = self.translate_amino(codon)
        if amino:
            protein.append(amino)
        else:
            print(f'The codon {codon} is not in self.mapper_1')
        i += 3
    if len(phrase) % 3:
        messages.error(request, 'DNA CHAIN INVALID')
        return ()
    else:
        return protein
```

Comment: @Marcgames_YT: no you need to replace `build_protein(protein, phrase)` with `build_protein(request, phrase)`, since the first parameter (well the second if you count `self` is `request`, not `protein`).

Comment: I do believe that solved my error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error stems from your error message (as you have quite rightly identified).  The first parameter to the messages function, is required to be an HTTP request. This seems to indicate that your 'request', does not meet that criteria. Try to substitute the request with 'self'. (you can verify this if you are using a debugger, by interrogating the parameters to determine which one holds the HTTP Request value). i.e. `messages.error(self, 'DNA CHAIN INVALID')` or `messages.error(self.request, 'DNA CHAIN INVALID')` depending on your originating call.